# Problems reading data from Binary store in /tmp/gradle14484220662220949872.bin offset 95036 exists? true

Tags: build, react-native

i got this error when i run this command "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug"
for creating a build of an app in react-native. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I am getting a similar error from yesterday and It is barely building my app. Still couldn't figure out any workaround.

Comment: suddenly the project wont build

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was one of the libraries causing the issue.
You can try updating the libraries to fix the Issue.
My case was due to

react-native-fbsdk > needs to be updated to > react-native-fbsdk-next,

Some other libraries you can try updating
@react-native-firebase/app
@react-native-firebase/messaging